# Seeing the float32 weight in a proto file

Tags: python, tensorflow, floating-point, protocol-buffers

I have converted the Google Inception trained model `.pb` file which reads like bellow:

```
A
mixed_9/join/concat_dimConst*

dtype0*
value   :
A
mixed_8/join/concat_dimConst*

dtype0*
value   :
A
mixed_7/join/concat_dimConst*

dtype0*
value   :
A
mixed_6/join/concat_dimConst*
```

using Google Protobuf `--decode_raw` which reads from stdin. Now, the output reads as  `.proto` file including the name of the layers and some encoded numbers. Here is the first 30 lines of `.proto` file:

```
syntax="proto2";
1 {
  1: "mixed_10/join/concat_dim"
  2: "Const"
  5 {
    1: "dtype"
    2 {
      6: 3
    }
  }
  5 {
    1: "value"
    2 {
      8 {
        1: 3
        2: ""
        7: "\003"
      }
    }
  }
1 {
  1: "mixed_9/join/concat_dim"
  2: "Const"
  5 {
    1: "dtype"
    2 {
      6: 3
    }
  }
```

Parsing the file, I am looking for the trained weights of inception model, for instance in this case:

```
1 {
  1: "Mul"
  2 {
    10: 108
    12: 0x7265646c6f686563
  }
  5 {
    1: "dtype"
    2 {
      6: 1
    }
  }
  5 {
    1: "shape"
    2 {
      7: ""
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, using a small python script I could print out all the tensors in the inception model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

INCEPTION_LOG_DIR = '/tmp/inception_v3_log'

if not os.path.exists(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR):
    os.makedirs(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename = './model/tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _= tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='')
 pprint([out for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if op.type != 'Placeholder' for out in op.values() if out.dtype == tf.float32])
```

I have generated all the layers of that model. So, that `Mul` layer corresponds to the middle line of the output of my Python script:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'mixed/join/concat_dim:0' shape=() dtype=int32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'Mul:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>,)
(<tf.Tensor 'conv/conv2d_params_quint8_const:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 32) dtype=quint8>,)
```

My issue is that I don't find a way to read these float32 values which I assume are the weights for each layer.

I have tried `protoc`v3.3 on my `.proto` file but I am receiving an error:

```
$ protoc inception.proto.utf --print_free_field_numbers
inception.proto.utf:2:1: Expected top-level statement (e.g. "message").
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.s: The `.pb` file of the inception_model is available [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb).

Comment: I'm assuming that it is actually the 0x7265646c6f686563 and is a 64-bit value. Any chance we can see the .proto? I can probably tell you what is wrong at the top. You could also try running the binary output through https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode, which IIRC also displays floating point - so if it matches your expected value, it will verify which field it is.

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell, I have placed the link of the `.pb` file in the updated question.

Comment: @MarcGravell, Also tested the first 1000 lines of that file using your tool and here is an example of the output: `0A = field 1, type String
UTF8: MulPlaceholder* dtype0* shape:�

0A = field 1, type String

03 = length 3

payload = 4D-75-6C

UTF8: Mul

12 = field 2, type String

0B = length 11

payload = 50-6C-61-63-65-68-6F-6C-64-65-72

UTF8: Placeholder

50 = field 10, type Variant

6C = 108 (raw) or 54 (zigzag)

61 = field 12, type Fixed64

63-65-68-6F-6C-64-65-72 = 8243105109859919203 (integer) or 1.14115223244741E+243 (floating point)`

Comment: is 1.1411...E+243 the number you were thinking of?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. @MarcGravell, I am interested in seeing all the weights associated with each tensor layer. I would like to see them all in a matrix like a shape to compare and evaluate. That was my whole point of using that model. Is there any way to accomplish that in your opinion?

Comment: impossible to say without seeing how the .proto and data fit together. In theory you can construct partial .proto models over the same data to read selective parts.

Comment: Is there a chance we get in touch by email?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your model doesn't have any variables (trained model parameters), or they have already been converted to constants before export, you'll also need to load variable values from a separate checkpoint file. They also mayb be difficult to load in because from what I understand .pb files don't save the collections variables were in when saved. `MetaGraphDef`s were created for this reason, and there's a good chance you'll be better off looking for a relevant one of these.

If your model truly doesn't have any variables, you should be able to get the values of that layer by running the session after loading the graph def.

```
session.run('Mul:0')
```

You may have to use a `feed_dict` if the model has placeholders.

Note: these won't be the weights of the layer, but the result of the multiplication.

Comment: Thanks @DomJack. Yes, I guess I need to have a `feed_dict` for the placeholder: `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Mul' with dtype float
  [[Node: Mul = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]` Could you provide an example on this case please?