# Defining a feed_dict for a plceholder in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, floating-point, placeholder

I am not good in Python. I would like to know how am I gonna be able to define a `feed_dict` for a placeholder in Tensforflow using Python. I did look up my question and the closest was in C++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804714/define-a-feed-dict-in-c-for-tensorflow-models).

Suppose I have the following tensor:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'Mul:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>,)
```

seeing it without a feed_dict:

```
print sess.run('Mul:0')
```

brings this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Mul' with dtype float
     [[Node: Mul = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you use placeholders to feed values to operations. Say you have a network with a training operation called `train_op`, and placeholders defined for your input data: `data`, and target labels: `target`. Then when you run your training loop, you would gather some training data and associated labels at each iteration and feed those to your training operation using the `feed_dict`. That looks like this:

```
for _ in range(num_iterations):
    # Gather a batch of training data and targets somehow...
    d = dataset.get_next_batch()
    t = dataset.get_next_target_batch()

    # Run the training operation
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={data: d, target: t})
```

So I am not sure that the use case you are demonstrating makes sense, but the above is typically how you use the `feed_dict`.

Comment: In general, I would like to see the weights of each layer in a neural network, that was why I used the pre-trained `.pb` file of Inception model. Could you let me know how we do this in a generic tensorflow project?

Comment: That doesn't seem related to your question. You can view the values of tensors by running something like `for var in tf.trainable_variables():` followed by `print('{}\n{}\n'.format(var.name, var.eval()))`.

Comment: Thanks, but his outputs nothing for me. I don't want to confuse you, but could you have a look at my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829802/seeing-the-float32-weight-in-a-proto-file?noredirect=1#comment78649582_45829802